# PHP -> REGEX | password validation not working

Tags: php, regex, validation, passwords

I use this (almost) complex password verification:

```
function is_password($password) {
    return preg_match("^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,20}$", $password);
}
```

So it must contain:

- one digit from 0-9,
- one lowercase character,
- one uppercase character,
- at least 6 characters
- at most 20 characters

This does not seem to work. Whenever I type certain characters like `e`, `t`, `o`, `j`, `c` and `b`; the function returns true if allowed length is correct. So uppercase and digit is not being validated..

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Never, ever, ever, *ever* limit the max length of a password the user can enter. 1. There is no good reason. 2. It very strongly suggests that you are storing them as plain text, which you should also never, ever, ever, *ever* do.

Comment: @Sammitch So very much agreement; the *only* limitation imposed by password validation should be if it's *long enough*. I don't want to have to use a number, a letter, sign language, and a sound effect in my password, and I never should have to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot to use [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). Use this code instead:

```
return preg_match("/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,20}$/", $password);
```

Or you may split each condition and use this code:

```
return mb_strlen($password)>=6 && mb_strlen($password)<=20
       && preg_match("/[a-z]+/", $password) && preg_match("/[A-Z]+/", $password)
       && preg_match("/[0-9]+/", $password);
```

Answer (score 6):

I would break this apart into multiple checks.  This will allow you to intelligently give feedback to the user (or to a log) as to why the password selection failed.

```
<?php
function is_password($password){
    if (strlen($password) < 6) {
        // too short
        return false;
    }
    if (strlen($password) > 20) {
        // too long
        return false;
    }
    if (!preg_match("/[A-Z]/", $password) {
        // no upper
        return false;
    }
    if (!preg_match("/[a-z]/", $password) {
        // no lower
        return false;
    }
    if (!preg_match("/[0-9]/", $password) {
        // no digit
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
?>
```

Comment: This approach also lets you easily add or remove restrictions as necessary in the future.